# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V

Tags: java, hibernate, crud

am very new to java programming.i downloaded a project from some website....

i am trying to run a hibernate project in Eclipse Juno.
when am running this project am getting the following errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244)
    at com.mycompany.ContactManager.main(ContactManager.java:24)

Comment: Codes please.Especially ContactManager class.

Comment: can you post your hibernate version

Answer (score 0):

You use different hibernate version, than the project has been written for.